# How do I keep track of a position in a NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm iterating over a large amount of lines of input, and for certain criteria I'm pulling some the lines out to build a result to display to the user. I'd like the last line that matches the criteria to be a different color. Currently I'm doing this

```
 endOfString = result.string.characters.count
 lengthOfLastString = tempResult.string.characters.count
```

And then when I'm ready to display the string I've built I do

```
let changeRange = NSRange(location: endOfString+1, length: lengthOfLastString)
result.addAttributes(singleAttribute, range: changeRange)
```

But this doesn't work because I end up blowing past the range of valid index on the String. I understand generally that Swift strings are more complex, so what is the method for doing something like this?

Sample data as requested :

> But treade the stranger pathes of banishment
>
> Rich. King them lay by their Helmets & their Speares, And both returne
>   backe to their Chaires againe:   Withdraw with vs, and let the
>   Trumpets sound,
>
> While we returne these Dukes what we Keyword decree.

I start caring about the line containing the word "King" and I want to capture all the lines up and including the line with "Keyword". That last line with "Keyword" is what I'd like to make a different color.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you include some sample data and what lines you want to highlight?

Comment: What is a "line", in your mind?

Comment: I'm iterating over my input like this : let lines = inString.characters.split {$0 == "\n" || $0 == "\r\n"}.map(String.init)  So from newline to newline.

Comment: If it were easier, I'd be fine with simply highlighting the Keyword itself. My main issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to define the NSRange that I need to apply the Attribute to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're building the output string, record endIndex prior to each append of a line. Then, after you add the last line, `savedIndex..<endIndex` is the range you're looking for.

Comment: When I do this:        let myRange = prevIndex..<endingIndex
        result.addAttributes(singleAttribute, range: NSRange(myRange)  I get : Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>') to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'

Comment: Try building an int-based range using not the index values (sorry) but the corresponding character counts. It's similar to what you were doing, but avoids the increment past the end